# PHP SQL, SELECT corresponding data from 3 tables at once?

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables, 'u' 'd' 's'

'u' has

- userid
- divid

'd' has

- divid
- divname

's' has

- sname
- primaryuserid
- secondaryuserid

Now what I'd like to do is display a table with rows of the following format

- userid, divname, sname

Plus figure out a way to decipher whether userid is a primary or secondary for this sname table.

I'm able to show userid and divname using a left join, but I don't know how I would add a third table? To make it trickier, there can be more than 1 snames for each userid, up to ~20. Is there a way to display 0-20 snames depending on the userid, separated with commas?

What I have currently is just and u and d tables corresponding to each other.

```
SELECT
    e.userid,
    e.divid, 
    d.divname 
FROM 
    e
LEFT JOIN d ON (e.divid = d.id)
ORDER BY e.userid
```

Comment: A little more explanation of how your tables relate to each other would help.  For example, could you give us the left join you're using already?

Comment: SELECT
  e.userid,
  d.divname
FROM
  e
LEFT JOIN d ON (e.divid = d.divid)
ORDER BY e.userid




Sorry about the lack of editing, I can't format it in the comment box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a couple of different things here. First of all, the "way to display 0-20 snames depending on the userid, separated with commas" can be done with MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, so your query would look like this (no distinction between primary and secondary yet):

```
SELECT u.userid,
    d.divname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.sname SEPARATOR ', ') AS "snames"
FROM u
    LEFT JOIN d ON d.divid = u.divid
    LEFT JOIN s ON (s.primaryuserid = u.userid OR s.secondaryuserid = u.userid);
```

Now, to be able to distinguish whether the user is primary or secondary, you have to get a little fancier. I'd probably do it with a union, like this:

```
SELECT u.userid,
    d.divname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.sname SEPARATOR ', ') AS "snames",
    'Primary' AS "category"
FROM u
    LEFT JOIN d ON d.divid = u.divid
    LEFT JOIN s ON s.primaryuserid = u.userid
UNION ALL
SELECT u.userid,
    d.divname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.sname SEPARATOR ', ') AS "snames",
    'Secondary' AS "category"
FROM u
    LEFT JOIN d ON d.divid = u.divid
    LEFT JOIN s ON s.secondaryuserid = u.userid
```

This will give you two rows (one Primary, one Secondary) for each userid with comma-separated lists of the snames.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables, and `s` twice for the two possible relations:

```
select 
    u.userid
,   d.divname
,   coalesce(s1.sname, s2.sname)
,   case when s1.sname is not null then 'Primary'
         when s2.sname is not null then 'Secondary'
         else 'None' end
from u
join d on d.divid = u.divid
left join s s1 on s1.primaryuserid = u.userid
left join s s2 on s2.secondaryuserid = u.userid
```

Displaying up to 20 usernames separated by comma's is best done on the client side, in PHP.  It is possible to do it in the database, but the method depends on your DBMS.  For MySQL, limiting a subquery to 20 rows is hard, but creating comma-separated lists is easy.  For example:

```
select
    group_concat(coalesce(s1.sname,s2.sname) separator ',')
,   ...
from u
...
group by u.userid
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the isnull call in the 4th line. MySQL's giving me errors and looking it up online makes it seem like it can only take in 1 parameter.

I think I may not have worded my question clearly enough regarding 's' and sname. sname will never be null, however, it might not have any userid's attached to it. It can have up to 2, a primary and secondary userid.

Comment: @user346325: RIght, `isnull` should be `coalesce` for MySQL.  It checks for null because if the left join to `s1` doesn't find anything, it will set all `s1` fields to null

Comment: I haven't tried the group_concat yet but it seems simple enough. Thanks for the coalesce approach. It simplifies the code a lot compared to what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Inner Join and put it in a view. Then we can just do a select on the view.